# Replacing repeated values of cell with empty [] - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

So I have a 1x348 cell composed of numbers and empty brackets. Ie ... [] [] [] [169] [170] [170] [170] [171] [172] [] []...
All what I want to do is change the repeated numbers to empty brackets []. I need to hold the places. I tried this, but am not having any success. It is also not ideal, because in the case with more than one repeat, it would just replace every other repeat with [].

```
for jj = 1:length(testcell);
    if testcell{jj} == testcell{jj-1}
        testcell{jj} = []
    end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing your code lacks is some variable to store current value:

```
current = testcell{1};
for jj = 2:length(testcell)
    if testcell{jj} == current
        testcell{jj} = [];
    else
        current = testcell{jj};
    end
end
```

But it's better to use [Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125741/replacing-repeated-values-of-cell-with-empty-matlab#20126004) =).

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have `{1,1,1}`. First iteration will change this to `{1,[],1}` and second iteration does not see any repetition. Thus iterating backwards is probably the easiest solution:

```
for jj = length(testcell):-1:2
    if testcell{jj} == testcell{jj-1}
        testcell{jj} = [];
    end
end
```

Then the first step will result in `{1,1,[]}` and the second in `{1,[],[]}`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `NaN` values to represent cells with empty matrices, and vectorize your code:

```
testcell(cellfun('isempty', testcell)) = {NaN};
[U, iu] = unique([testcell{end:-1:1}]);
testcell(setdiff(1:numel(testcell), numel(testcell) - iu + 1)) = {NaN};
testcell(cellfun(@isnan, testcell)) = {[]};
```

Comment: +1 for the quoted version of `isempty` in `cellfun`!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. This also uses `unique` to handle cases where repeated values are not consecutive, but maybe it's an overkill.